# How would it be to live in a very small universe, let´s say 20x20 square meters?

Tags: photons, universe, curvature

Let´s consider a curved universe that is very small, say 20 square meters and not expanding.

If you stood at the middle of this tiny universe and looked forward, you wouldn´t see any walls, since it is curved. But you would see your back. 
If you looked left you would see your right side of your body, and when looking right you would see the left side of you body.

Is that how it would be?

Or would the photons that your body emits be all over the space in the room, so you would consider yourself to be disseminated all over the room so it would be impossible to see the shape of your own body?

Comment: even so the question is curious but you must be more specific, is the curvature positive of negative? is your universe closed? are there any singularities? if your answers are positive,Yes,No I think your last statement is the most convenient.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but this video might be interesting for you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k3_B9Eq7eM

Comment: Have you ever played Pacman?

Answer (score -1):

You are talking about the end of the universe. [There are three possibilities,](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=166) but the first is the most relevant:

The universe is a sphere. Assuming your universe would have all of the physics of ours, think of this like a radically smaller Earth itself: if you found yourself in one point, you would arrive at that same point no matter what if you kept moving forward in one direction. The problem is that you wouldn't theoretically see yourself since you would see the *horizon*.

Comment: Which horizon?
Also, the OP doesn't ask about the "end of the universe", but rather about the implications of a very small and (I presume positively curved) Universe.

Comment: The Earth is curved, right? Think of this: http://www.merriam-webster.com/art/dict/azimuth.htm and the respective definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horizon

Comment: Five minute limit, oy. The useful video up above explains this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k3_B9Eq7eM&t=4m5s

Comment: But we are not talking bout the earth, we are talking about a Universe. A horizon is not a well-defined term in physics, it has several different meanings, and linking to a dictionary entry of a meaning from geography, not physics, is not that helpful.

Btw, the video you are linking to exactly states that  you could see multiple copies of yourself in a tiny Unievrse with periodic boundary conditions, not mantioning a horizon anywhere.